# PHP Comparison With Or Without Brackets

Tags: php, comparison

Are these two PHP comparisons exactly the same? By that I mean, will the result be the same for both statements; with and without brackets?

Without brackets:

```
if ( $params['isAjax'] == '1' && $isEnabled == '1' ) {
    ...
}
```

And with brackets enclosing each statement:

```
if ( ($params['isAjax'] == '1') && ($isEnabled == '1') ) {
    ...
}
```

Additionally, which is the *better* method. Is one superior to another? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Brackets are only needed when the operator precedence will change your logic: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: As far as which one is better or superior, it's just a matter of opinion (in my opinion.)

Comment: By and large, it is "industry" standard to see the first if-statement, without the (relatively) unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: Would you be so kind and let us know whether you found another solution (and answer your question on your own in this case - so we can also benefit from your investigations) or one of the given answers fitted your needs (and mark the adäquate answer as accepted in this case to honor the communities efforts)? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exactly the same. Order of operations dictates that `==` evaluates before `&&`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are logically equal

`if ( (true) && (true) )`

is the same as

`if ( true && true )`

grouping statements using `()` is effective when you want to group logical statements

```
if ( (true && true) || false ) //true
if ( (true && false) || false ) //false
if ( (true && false) || true ) //true
if ( (true || false) && true ) //true
if ( (true || false) && false ) //false
```

without grouping these statements would be

```
if ( true && true || false ) //true
if ( true && false || false ) //false
if ( true && false || true ) //true
if ( true || false && true ) //true
if ( true || false && false ) //true <-- different
```

Grouping statements make it more readable as well as removes unwanted results (i didnt know `( true || false && false )` was true).